# Copy paste a row from one sheet to another

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to copy rows from Sheet1 which meet a crieteria and post the whole row at the end of the current data. I am able to copy the row but it is not pasting it. Help will be appreciated. Here is my code I have written:

```
Sub Button1_Click()

Dim i As Integer

'Range("H2:O65536").ClearContents

Sheets("Sheet1").Select
LastRowColA = Range("A65536").End(xlUp).Row

For i = 2 To LastRowColA

If Cells(i, 6) = "No" Then
Rows(i).Select
Rows(i).Copy

Sheets("Sheet2").Select
Dim LastRow As Long
Dim StartRow As Long
Dim Col As Long
Dim Row As Long

StartRow = 2
Col = 1
LastRow = findLastRow(1)

For Row = StartRow To LastRow
Rows(LastRow).Select
ActiveSheet.Paste

Next Row

Else
'do nothing
End If
Next i
End Sub


Function findLastRow(ByVal Col As Integer) As Long
    'Find the last row with data in a given column

    findLastRow = Cells(Rows.Count, Col).End(xlUp).Row
End Function
```

Answer (score 4):

here we go: a tad shorter, but should do the job...

```
Sub Button1_Click()
Dim i As Integer
Dim ws1 As Worksheet: Set ws1 = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1")
Dim ws2 As Worksheet: Set ws2 = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet2")

For i = 2 To ws1.Range("A65536").End(xlUp).Row
    If ws1.Cells(i, 6) = "No" Then ws1.Rows(i).Copy ws2.Rows(ws2.Cells(ws2.Rows.Count, 6).End(xlUp).Row + 1)
Next i
End Sub
```

Answer (score 3):

To add a bit more help, why spend all that (processing) time looping through a potentially large row set when you can just filter and copy all your data at once?

See code below. You may need to tweak it a bit to match your data set.

```
Sub Button1_Click()

Dim ws1 as Worksheet: Set ws1 = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1")
Dim ws2 as Worksheet: Set ws2 = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet2")

With ws1

    .UsedRange.AutoFilter 6, "No" 
    '-> assumes data starts in column A, if not adjust the 6

    Intersect(.UsedRange,.UsedRange(Offset(1)).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Copy  
    ' -> assumes No's are there, if they may not exist, will need to error trap.

End With

With ws2

    .Rows(.Cells(ws2.Rows.Count, 6).End(xlUp).Row + 1).PasteSpecial xlPasteValues

End With

ws1.AutoFilterMode = False

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

// Just use it.

```
Sheet2.Select (Sheet1.Rows(index).Copy)

Sheet2.Paste (Rows(index))
```

If you want to copy, paste two or more rows then use the for loop.